# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value to save to Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift2

I'm trying to save a new Entity into Core Data and when it gets to the part where I am trying to make a mutable copy  so that I can update the NSMutableOrderedSet and then save it back into Core Data.

currentPerson equals an Entity called Person.
That Entity has an relationship called statements which is toMany and represents the Entity Statement. That is the ordered list that I am trying to access for the first time.

I'm new to Core Data but I think this is the link that seems to be causing the crash.

```
let statements = currentPerson.statements!.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableOrderedSet;
```

And here is most of the block of code:

```
// try to convet the string to an Int
        if let number = Int(amountNumberString) {
            let myNumber = NSNumber(integer:number).floatValue
            print(myNumber)

            // save the new Statement
            let statementEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Statement", inManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context);

            let newStatement = Statement(entity: statementEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.context)

            newStatement.name = statementName.text

            //formate the number into a decimal to save it to core data
            let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
            formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true

            var newDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber!()
            newDecimalNumber = formatter.numberFromString(amountNumberString) as? NSDecimalNumber
            newStatement.amount = newDecimalNumber


            // Insert the new Statement into the Current Persons's statement set
            let statements = currentPerson.statements!.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableOrderedSet;

            statements.addObject(newStatement);

            currentPerson.statements = statements.copy() as? NSOrderedSet;

            // save the manged object context
            coreDataStack.saveContext()

        } else {
            print("'\(statementAmount.text)' did not convert to an Int")
            // display warning about not having a valid amount
            let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Opps!", message: "The amount is not a valid number.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                print("Handle Ok logic here")
            }))

            presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
```

Is it finding the statements attribute to be empty when its trying to copy it?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out what the issue was, currentPerson was never being set after it was created.

Comment: Consider using optional chaining and messaging yourself whenever optionals aren't behaving as you intend them to do. This will make it easier for you to track errors as this one, as---using optional chaining---you wont get a runtime error but self-controlled throws/messages. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503729/why-does-swift-2-favor-forced-unwrap-over-optionals/34503897